# DropDown In Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I need to add a dropdown in a Kendo Grid. I have tried to add by using EditorTemplate but something is not right in the code that's why it is not working for me.The dropdown have 3 values (Donate, Refund, Undo). Below is my kendo grid and i need to display dropdown on the first column. Please help.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<GA.CustomerCare.Web.Synergy.Models.CustomerOrderARInfo>
                    (Model.CustomerOrderARInfoResult)
                    .Name("SearchResultsGridParent")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(e => e.ActionList).Width(100).EditorTemplateName("ActionDropdownEditor");
                        columns.Bound(e => e.TransNumber).Width(85);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.OriginalTransNumber).Width(85);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.DateEntered).Width(115);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.TransDate).Width(85);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.TransType).Width(130);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.Status).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.Amount).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.AmountApplied).Width(100);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.AvailableFunds).Width(85);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.AdjustmentReason).Width(85);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.CcCheckGiftCard).Width(155);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.PaypalTransID).Width(135);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.Area).Width(85);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.EnteredBy).Width(115);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.Reference).Width(155);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.DateCapture).Width(155);
                        columns.Bound(e => e.AmountCapture).Width(155);

                    })
                    .Sortable(sortable => sortable
                    .AllowUnsort(true)
                    .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn)
                    )
                    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                    .ColumnResizeHandleWidth(10)
                    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(190))
                    //.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
                                                        //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetCustomerOrderAR", "Order", new { CustomerOrderID = Model.CustomerOrderID }))
                    )
                                                        )
```

Below is the property i am using in the Model :

```
  [Display(Name = "ActionList")]
    public string ActionList { get; set; }
```

Below is my ActionDropdownEditor :

```
@model string

   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("ActionList")  //Important, must match the column's name
        .Value(Model)
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .BindTo(new string[] { "Donate", "Refund", "Undo" }))
```

Answer (score 1):

I also tried using the kendo Grid with DropDown in the same way as you did and it worked.
Please check it with your code whether some references are missing.

```
column.Bound(p => p.ActionList).ClientTemplate("#= ActionList !=null ? ActionList : '' #").EditorTemplateName("_Sex").Title("ActionList");
```

I am giving my whole Dropdown in EditorTemplates Folder for you to check with your code:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                .Name("ActionList").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:12px", @class = "PaxType" })
                  .BindTo(new string[] { "Donate", "Refund", "Undo" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a DropDownList into a Kendo Grid by using html in a ClientTemplate. I achieved something similar using the following...

```
column.Bound(p => p.WFKeyType).Title("Type").ClientTemplate("<select class='form-control'><option value='' disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Select Key Type</option><option value='String'>String</option><option value='Integer'>Integer</option><option value='DateTime'>DateTime</option><option value='Currency'>Currency</option><option value='Bool'>Bool</option></select>");
```

which produces a DropDownList in the Grid Column containing 'String', 'Integer', 'DateTime', 'Currency', & 'Bool' as options. The 'form-control' class is from Bootstrap and helps the column look more clean. Your project would need to add Bootstrap 3 before the class would be accessible.